# Implementing inherited abstract member with generic

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

say I have a class:

```
abstract class A<T> {
    public abstract void foo(T a);
}

class B : A<int> {
    public void foo(int a) {              //ERROR, signature is not correct
}
```

How do I implement the base class in this case? The type of the parameter should be int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you are missing the override keyword.

However, I want to caution you to be very careful with this pattern. You can get yourself into a world of hurt if you're not careful:

```
class B<T>
{
  public virtual void M(T t) {}
  public virtual void M(int x) {}
}
class D : B<int>
{
  public override void M(int x) {}
}
```

Which one did it override?

No good whatsoever comes of this situation. The CLR specification recommends that you never get yourself into a situation where two method signatures unify under generic construction. Good advice, that.

Comment: You might think this is a silly example. But imagine you're implementing a bi-directional dictionary; you could end up doing this: `class BiDic<T,U> { public T this[U u] { get { ... } } public U this[T t] { get { ... } } }` - and it will work - as long as you don't use the same type for `T` and `U`

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the `override` keyword:

```
class B : A<int> {
    public override void foo(int a) {
}
```

Without `override` the compiler expects a *different* signature, expecting that you are declaring an *overload*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `override` keyword:

```
public override void foo(int a) {;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class N<T> 
{
    public abstract void foo(T a);
}

class B : N<int>
{
    public override void foo(int a)
    {              
    }
}
```